# AM2302 (DHT22) wrong readings when temperature < 0 ˚C

Tags: rust, banana-pi, libgpiod

When temp is over 0 ˚C it seem OK.
When temp is under 0 ˚C I'm getting weird values:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Parsed:
Humidity:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] 3
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1] 121
```

Temp:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1] 15
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] 234
```

Checksum:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] 117
```

Checksum is OK and these values gives me:

```
3×256+121 = 88.9 %
15×256+234 = 407.4 ˚C
```

which is weird when outside temp is ~ -1,5 ˚C

in specification when under 0 ˚C the first bit of temperature should be 1 but there is 1 on first bit of second byte of temperature.

this is rust code decoding readouts:

```rust
pub struct Reading {
    pub temperature: f32,
    pub humidity: f32,
}

impl Reading {
    pub fn from_binary_vector(data: &[u8]) -> Result<Self, CreationError> {
        if data.len() != 40 {
            return Err(CreationError::WrongBitsCount);
        }

        let bytes: Result<Vec<u8>, ConversionError> = data
            .chunks(8)
            .map(|chunk| -> Result<u8, ConversionError> { convert(chunk) })
            .collect();

        let bytes = match bytes {
            Ok(this_bytes) => this_bytes,
            Err(_e) => return Err(CreationError::MalformedData),
        };

        // let check_sum: u8 = bytes[..4].iter().sum();
        let check_sum: u8 = bytes[..4]
            .iter()
            .fold(0 as u8, |result, &value| result.overflowing_add(value).0);
        if check_sum != bytes[4] {
            return Err(CreationError::ParityBitMismatch);
        }

        let raw_humidity: u16 = (bytes[0] as u16) * 256 + bytes[1] as u16;
        let raw_temperature: i16 = if bytes[2] >= 128 {
            bytes[3] as i16 * -1
        } else {
            (bytes[2] as i16) * 256 + bytes[3] as i16
        };

        let humidity: f32 = raw_humidity as f32 / 10.0;
        let temperature: f32 = raw_temperature as f32 / 10.0;

        println!("{} {} {} {} {}, {}H, {}T",bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3], bytes[4],  humidity, temperature);

        if !(-41.0..=81.0).contains(&temperature) {
            return Err(CreationError::OutOfSpecValue);
        }
        if !(0.0..=99.9).contains(&humidity) {
            return Err(CreationError::OutOfSpecValue);
        }

        Ok(Reading {
            temperature,
            humidity,
        })
    }
}
```

Is sensor wrong or just sends something different to specification?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not about programming. This is off-topic on this site, and your question will probably be closed. If you want to ask about a **specific behavior of your code** (rust I presume from tag) you have to provide a minimal reproducible example of it.

Comment: added code maybe the mistake is there

Comment: Would you mind to link a datasheet showing the exact transmission protocol, please? If we assume a 12-bit signed value, `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]` is 0xFEA, which is -22. According to your formula, this is -2,2°C, looks promising.

Comment: Looked for datasheet but didn't found. It's from aliexpress, Assumed it's standard AM2302. Discovered in customer's review: `Temperature sensor doesn’t work properly with any Arduino libraries. At negative temperature it shows 409,5C when it supposed to be -0,1C.` 
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005487188275.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.51.16b118025i6C7i#nav-description
Your suggestion seem to be the right way since same shift of values in review and my readout value.

Comment: If you run Linux there, why don't you use in-kernel driver? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/humidity/dht11.c

Comment: I believe it could hardly handle non standard data either :-)

Comment: Have you tried? And if it becomes true, why not to fix? Using in-kernel drivers is preferred and has a few benefits.

Comment: No I didn't tried. I'd like to manage several GPIO lines from one manageable application. If gpiod uses front of actions I considered better to read multiline sensors at once, then drive another GPIO lines in meantime. Yes I could modify original kernel driver but I use 3 vendors of DHT22/AM2302 so I'd have to use two drivers, mess with dts. I don't know if it would be better solution at all. Is there any well written guide anywhere? Thanks for finding another possibilities :-)

Comment: At least this is the **recommended** way of how to describe and enable hardware in Linux. There is a documetation about DT, about this certain bindings and so on. Perhaps somebody already done this and made a blog post… (first googled: https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/148-hardware/14423-pi-iot-in-python-using-linux-drivers-the-dht22.html). Here seems relevant discussion with useful links: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=98543.

Comment: One more: https://www.leaflabs.com/news/2017/3/7/using-linux-device-trees-for-fun-and-profit (seems most practical). And so on… Definitely you are not the first one who wants to use this sensor in Linux.

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add `@USER` to them. It is by luck I have checked this question again.)

Comment: @0andriy I've checked kernel code for sensor and it seem to me it's solution for standard DHT11/22/AM2302 not this 12 bit signed integer communication "enhanced" ones. Still I don't fully understand implementation code but https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/humidity/dht11.c#L152 seem decode only standard transmission protocol.
Moreover in my custom code I'm able to detect last good readouts which is important for my project also. I'm still not convinced kernel solution will fit better even with modified driver code.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze would You mind to remove -1 at topic? It gets out that findings regards this question could be very useful for users equipped by this nonstandard sensors since it describes the problem and a way how to decode data from them properly. Not particularly for me, I have answers already but the others.

Comment: If you think the kernel code may be improved, improve it! It helps tens or hundreds people and while providing the standard interface. Custom solutions are discouraged. (See also "NIH syndrome" and "reinventing a wheel")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temperature seems to use a 12-bit signed value, according to your findings:

> 407.4 ˚C [...] when outside temp is ~ -1,5 ˚C

> At negative temperature it shows 409,5C when it supposed to be -0,1C.

With the factor of 10 taken from your source, the following table shows the relations.

| Your measurement | Unsigned decimal | 12-bit hex | Signed decimal | Actual measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 407,4 °C | 4074 | 0xFEA | -22 | -2,2 °C |
| 409,5 °C | 4095 | 0xFFF | -1 | -0,1 °C |

Therefore, change your code to this and it will show the correct temperature:

```rust
        let raw_temperature: i16 = if bytes[2] >= 0x8 {
            (bytes[2] as i16) * 0x100 + bytes[3] as i16 - 0x1000
        } else {
            (bytes[2] as i16) * 0x100 + bytes[3] as i16
        };
```

Why the subtraction of 0x10 in case of `bytes[2] >= 0x8`?

This "shifts" the range `0x800..0xFFF` down to the range `-0x800..-0x001` (0x0800 - 0x1000 = -0x800 and 0x0FFF - 0x1000 = -0x001).

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was related to the DHT22 sensor supply voltage where I was using 3.3v instead of 5v. The DHT22 specs say you can use between 6 and 3.3 volts but some units do strange things at 3.3 volts. I have a few sensors from the same vendor and with the same code, some were ok but others giving strange numbers like 0 or even -3500. Once I switched to 5v supply for all the DHT22 sensors the numbers were ok.

Update: for one of my DHT22 sensors it seems to just goes wonky after a couple of days. I found the fix for this was to have the esp32 restart itself every 24 hours using ESP.restart().

Comment: I already use 5V and shielded cables. After apply of 12bit signed code, outside sensor shows sane values. I suppose 3V3 on longer distance drops to lower voltage under limit.
Testing reading in 5 secs interval and reading is about 50-70% successful. It's because sometimes GPIO reads with latency so it reads wrong values which is in about 98% filtered by checksum or scale sanity check.